# How do you add a CSS style to a HTML file with a python http.server?

Tags: python, html, css, server

I have a simple http server running from python which returns an HTML file as a GET request. The HTMl file just has some input and it is sent correctly but is not styled even though it is linked to a CSS file. Here is the server.py:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            h = open("main.html", "rb")
            self.wfile.write(h.read())
    def do_POST(s):
        if s.path == '/':
            s.path = './main.html'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

main.html is this

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./output.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="mx-auto text-center mt-8 px-0 py-8 border border-4 border-solid border-gray-600"
        style="width: 700!important;">CHECKBOX INPUT</h1>
    <div class="flex h-full mx-auto">
        <form action="">
            <div class="w-3/4 py-10 px-8">
                <table class="table-auto">

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mr-64">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-8 w-8">
                                    <label class="ml-4">test</label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mr-64">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-8 w-8">
                                    <label class="ml-4"></label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mr-64">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-8 w-8">
                                    <label class="ml-4">test</label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mr-64">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-8 w-8">
                                    <label class="ml-4">test</label>
                                </div>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="px-4  py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mx-auto">
                                    <span>TEXT INPUT:</span>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-input mt-4">
                                    <select>
                                        <option value="value1" selected>DROPDOWN</option>
                                        <option value="valeu2">Value 2</option>
                                        <option value="valeu3">Value 3</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="px-4  py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mx-auto">

                                </div>

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="px-4  py-10 h-4">
                                <div class="mx-auto">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="bg-gray-600 p-4 border-0 border-solid rounded-lg">
                                </div>

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Even though the HTMl file is linked to output.css when I host the server it returns the HTML file without any styling

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried using `href="/output.css"` without the leading dot?  basically an href with just a leading `/` has the browser try to fetch the resource at the same host and port as it found the html.  putting that href in a doc served @  `http://example.com:8000/bar.html` will result in a fetch `http://example.com:8000/output.css`  However you `doGet` will probably need to decide between main.html and output.css based on request URL.

Answer (score 0):

When your HTML file is loaded in browser it tries to load CSS file (`./output.css`). Since you serve this page over HTTP browser makes HTTP request to get this output.css file but apparently your server doesn't serve this CSS file.

Comment: You need to make your server serve that CSS file as well, your server should check the request URL and return the file that's requested.
Why do you need to create a server yourself? I'd suggest to use popular backend solutions like Flask or Django where you can configure serving static files easily.

Comment: its a school project i have to use python to make an HTTP server, could you give me an example of the code used to serve the CSS file because I need it to return main.html but it needs to be styled

Comment: Do it similarly as you return your main.html file, just check the request URL, if it ends with  `output.css` then return CSS file instead of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Its really complicated to do so, because you have to create new server that serve your css file.
**Better you used Powerfull & popular solutions likeFlask and Django **where you can configure these files easily.
for more info about Flask
https://pymbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flask.html

Answer (score 0):

is your html file or css file in a folder?
if so change in the html file the link to "[folder name]/output.css"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just had to figure this out myself. You've likely solved this already but incase anyone else stumbles across this, here's what I came up with, working great!

```
def do_GET(self):
    # Cache request
    path = self.path

    # Validate request path, and set type
    if path == "/resources/index.html":
        type = "text/html"
    elif path == "/resources/script.js":
        type = "text/javascript"
    elif path == "/resources/style.css":
        type = "text/css"
    elif path == "/favicon.ico":
        path = "/resources/favicon.ico"
        type = "image/x-icon"
    else:
        # Wild-card/default
        if not path == "/":
            print("UNRECONGIZED REQUEST: ", path)
            
        path = "/resources/index.html"
        type = "text/html"
    
    # Set header with content type
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", type)
    self.end_headers()
    
    # Open the file, read bytes, serve
    with open(path[1:], 'rb') as file: 
        self.wfile.write(file.read()) # Send
```